# Is there any development materials about ATL service

Tags: c++, windows

I want to develop a Windows service and choose ATL service as I want to use native C++, but it seems there are not much materials on this topic, I only found some concept description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x(VS.80).aspx), which is not enough for me to develop my service application.

Do you know any tutorials or samples on developing a ATL service?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You want to write C++ web application? Why wouldn't you choose something better like CppCMS?

Comment: No, just a windows service application

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @freefallr See below the answer that I composed myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there would be little chance to have an better answer as ATL is really not that popular now. But to make this post valuable to others who might meet this problem in the future, I would like to give my answers based on what I found:

Yes, it is really had to find materials on developing ATL service, if what you want is just to write a Windows service application in Native C++, following links might be helpful:

- [A Windows Service
  Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Sund_WindowService.aspx)
- [Creating a Simple Win32 Service in C++](http://blog.csdn.net/todototry/archive/2007/04/16/1566479.aspx)
- [CNTService](http://www.naughter.com/serv.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. There isn't. The last book I brought on ATL is out of print and unless you're familiar with COM I might suggest this is not the best way to go. You can write a Windows Service without ATL of course. VS2005 even has a wizard for this very purpose.

The last time I wrote a NT service that wasn't C# (which works well) I used a sample class from CodeProject. Some 10 years ago alas.